# Convert any non-singular square matrix to a strictly diagonally dominant one using only elementary row operations

Tags: matrices, gaussian-elimination

> **Elementary row operations**
>
> 1. Swap the positions of two of the rows.
> 2. Multiply one of the rows by a nonzero scalar.
> 3. Add or subtract the scalar multiple of one row to another row.

> **Strictly diagonally dominant matrix**
>
> An $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is strictly diagonally dominant is the absolute value of each entry on the main diagonal is greater than the sum of the absolute values of the other entries in the same row.
> $$|a_{ii}|>\sum^n_{j\ne i}|a_{ij}|, \text{ for all i}$$

Some non-singular matrices can be converted into a strictly diagonally dominant one using only elementary row operations. For example:
\begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 6 & -1 \\
    6 & 15 & 2\\ 1 & 1 & 54
\end{pmatrix}

$15R_1 - 6R_2$
\begin{pmatrix}
    -6 & 0 & -27 \\
    6 & 15 & 2\\ 1 & 1 & 54
\end{pmatrix}

$2R_1 +R_3$
\begin{pmatrix}
    -11 & 1 & 0 \\
    6 & 15 & 2\\ 1 & 1 & 54
\end{pmatrix}

However I have not yet found a concrete algorithm which is guaranteed to form a strict diagonally dominant matrix from any starting matrix.

My question is inspired by the condition of convergence of [Gauss-Jacobi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method) and [Gauss-Seidel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method) methods:

> A sufficient (but not necessary) condition for the Gauss-Jacobi/Gauss-Seidel iterative methods to converge is that the matrix $A$ is strictly or irreducibly diagonally dominant.
>
> [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method#Convergence)

#### Note

The transformed matrix should be in a form that can be used for the Gauss-Jacobi/Gauss-Seidel method. Applying [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) and then multiplying each row by some non-zero constant yields a strict diagonally dominant matrix. However matrices in this form cannot be used for the Gauss-Jacobi/Gauss-Seidel method. **This means that on top of being strictly diagonally dominant, each row of the matrix should contain at least 2 non-zero values.**

```
Matrix below is invalid for Gauss-Jacobi/seidel:
1 0 0 0 
0 2 0 0 
0 0 3 0 
0 0 0 4 

Matrix below is valid for Gauss-Jacobi/seidel:
5 1 0 0 
0 2 0 -1 
0 1 3 -1 
1 0 0 4
```

## My attempt

Here's an algorithm I came up with for obtaining a **non-strict** diagonally dominant matrix:

Given a **non-singular** $n\times n$ square matrix,

1. Convert matrix to reduced row echelon form using [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination). Result is an identity matrix:

```
1 0 0 0 ... 0
0 1 0 0 ... 0
0 0 1 0 ... 0
.     .     .
.       .   .
0 0 ... 0 1 0
0 0 ... 0 0 1
```

2. Starting from top row, add each row to the row directly below it $(R_1 + R_2, R_2+R_3, …)$. Each row, except last row, will contain the pattern 11 :

```
1 1 0 0 ... 0
0 1 1 0 ... 0
0 0 1 1 ... 0
.     .     .
.       .   .
0 0 ... 0 1 1
0 0 ... 0 0 1
```

3. Perform $R_n + R_{n-1}$

```
1 1 0 0 ... 0
1 2 1 0 ... 0
0 1 2 1 ... 0
.     .     .
.       .   .
0 0 ... 1 2 1
0 0 ... 0 1 2
```

At this point, we obtain a non-strict diagonally dominant matrix.

Is it possible to extend this algorithm to obtain a strictly diagonally dominant matrix? Or is there an algorithm for converting any non-singular square matrix into a strictly diagonally dominant one using only elementary row operations?

## Updates

Thanks to Jean Marie
I found an [algorithm in Matlab](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/78571-rearranging-rows-for-gauss-seidel-method) that rearranges rows for Gauss-Seidel. However, I was unable to execute the code on an [online compiler](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_matlab_online.php) due to a bug in the code. Also, it looks like the algorithm has some limitations:

- It assumes that each row of the matrix has a dominant term.
- It is only capable of row swapping.

Comment: Here is a general algorithm : https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/78571-rearranging-rows-for-gauss-seidel-method using graph methods (bipartite graphs + Ford-Fulkerson algorithm).

Comment: This kind of methods enters into the very general calling : "pre-conditionning" that can be useful for further queries you  might have to do.

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you. Unfortunately, I get an error when running the the general algorithm given on an online [matlab compiler](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_matlab_online.php). Also do you have an explanation for the last step of the algorithm "For each edge form i in I to j in J, that carries a non-zero flow, put copy values of row i in original matrix to row j in new matrix." Is this using the elementary row operations?

Comment: For your second question : Yes, for example left-multiplying a matrix $M$ by the $3 \times 3$ elementary matrix $E_{2,3}=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0}$ exchanges in $M$ the rows $2 \leftrightarrow 3$.

Comment: For your first question, I suppose you have used the "ready-to-use" program. But was the input the under the correct format ? Which error message was given ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I used the input given in the code itself:  `Command failed: octave -qf --no-window-system demo.m
warning: function /home/cg/root/643eabef11a84/demo.m shadows a core library function
error: parse error near line 44 of file /home/cg/root/643eabef11a84/demo.m

  nested functions not implemented in this context

>>>     function F = findPath(A)            % BFS (Breadth-first Search)
               ^`

Comment: @JeanMarie On closer inspection, the algorithm you shared does not look very promising. First of all, it assumes that the initial matrix has a dominant term for each row. This is not always the case. Secondly, the algorithm is capable of only row swapping and does not  seem capable  of performing the second and third elementary row operations. For matrices like $\begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 3 & 4\\
    0& -5& -10\\ 24& 14& 0
\end{pmatrix}$, I don't see it working.

Comment: In the case you give, you could work on the transpose of this matrix which has dominant entries on each of its lines; but this isn't an answer : there will be many matrices for which this will not be possible neither on rows nor on columns there will be I am sorry. I thought that, being present on the Matlab site, the algorithm had been validated by some community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, in the 2nd and 3rd phase of your attempt, you can add a non-unity and sufficiently small multiple of a row to another. Check this out:

Given any invertible matrix $A$:

1- Apply Gaussian elimination to $A$ to yield the identity matrix $I_n$.

Result: $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&\cdots &0&0\\0&1&0&\cdots &0&0\\0&0&1&\cdots &0&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\cdots &1&0\\0&0&0&\cdots&0 &1\\\end{bmatrix}.$$

2- Add to each row an $\epsilon$-multiple of its next row, when possible (this leaves you with a $1\epsilon$-pattern matrix, rather than a $11$-pattern matrix).

Result: $$\begin{bmatrix}1&\epsilon&0&\cdots &0&0\\0&1&\epsilon&\cdots &0&0\\0&0&1&\cdots &0&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\cdots &1&\epsilon\\0&0&0&\cdots&0 &1\\\end{bmatrix}.$$

3- Add to each row an $\epsilon$-multiple of its previous row, when possible (do it from the last row to the first, in the reversed order of phase 2).

Result: $$\begin{bmatrix}1&\epsilon&0&\cdots&0 &0&0\\\epsilon&1+\epsilon^2&\epsilon&\cdots&0 &0&0\\0&\epsilon&1+\epsilon^2&\cdots &0&0&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\cdots&\epsilon &1+\epsilon^2&\epsilon\\0&0&0&\cdots&0&\epsilon &1+\epsilon^2\\\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Interesting. It is important to note that strict diagonal dominance will occur only when  $-1 < \epsilon < 1$ and $\epsilon \ne 0$ because of first row.